# How to properly pass a string to a tflite model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have build a model for text classification (the input is a string, the output is a scalar) that I would like to quantize and deploy as a tensorflow lite model. I successfully converted the model to tflite and quantized it, but I'm unable to pass a string to the model for inference.

What I'm attempting to do, is create a minimally reproducible example of inference with the tflite model, which I can then provide to my company's engineering group so they can deploy it.

The following code works:

```
original_keras_model(tf.convert_to_tensor([testgood, testbad]))
```

It correctly outputs two scalars.

The following code does not work:

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="./final_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = tf.convert_to_tensor([testgood, testbad])
#input_data2 = tf.reshape(input_data[0], input_shape)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
```

In particular, `set_tensor` returns this error: `ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 2 but expected 1 for dimension 0 of input 0.`

I have tried passing only one example instead of two. In that case I get the error: `ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 0 but expected 1 for input 0.`

The input details are:

```
[{'name': 'serving_default_text_vectorization_input:0',
  'index': 0,
  'shape': array([1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([-1], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.bytes_,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the dimensions of the input_data after converting them to a tensor?

Comment: I had. It turned out that the problem was that tflite expects to receive a numpy tensor, not a tensorflow tensor. Which is bizarre, but that did it.

Comment: Interesting. [This example](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python) also uses a numpy array for inference, provided that the model doesn't have SignatureDefs defined. Maybe that's your case.